# Spring Data Solr, Querying with IS_NULL and OR

Tags: spring, oracle, solr

I have a query in Oracle:

```
WHERE
  (p_name IS NULL OR cp.name LIKE '%' || UPPER (p_name) || '%')
AND
  (p_cnum IS NULL OR CP.WSS_CUSTNUMBER LIKE p_cnum || '%')
AND
  (p_short_name IS NULL OR CP.SHORT_NAME LIKE '%' || UPPER (p_short_name) || '%')
AND
  ROWNUM < 1000
AND
  RR.ROLE_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name;
```

How can transform this query to Spring Data Solr (where `p_name`, `p_cnum` and `p_short_name` are inputs value)?